# Clean mechanism to save and restore a list of memory locations?

Tags: c++

I have a list of memory locations that I need to access both as a group, and occasionally individually. I would like to provide a single specification point. The current design is messy, and I was wondering if anyone had a good (ideally C++ish) way of approaching this.

I have a huge list of potential memory locations, of which each product will (at design time) select up to around 100 of them, split more or less evenly into two groups.

At a certain point in the code, we copy ALL of the memory locations out to a buffer, and then occasionally read them back from both the original location and the stored away buffer. After a certain length of time (and ~50,000 lines of code later), we will Restore the saved data back to Memory.

**Current Code (sorta)**

What we are currently doing something like the following:

```
#define BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS1 = 0x1400, 0x1450
#define BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS2 = BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS1, 0x1000, 0x1002, 0x2040, 0xFFFF

union {

    struct {
        struct {          // Must be kept in sync with BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS1
            uint16_t Mem1400;
            uint16_t Mem1450;
        } List1;
        uint16_t Mem1000;       // Must be kept in sync with BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS2
        uint16_t Mem1002;
        uint16_t Mem2040;
    } BlockList;

    uint16_t BlockArray[sizeof(BlockList)/sizeof(uint16_t)];

 } MemoryBlock;

uint32_t BASE_PTR = 0x30300000;


// block.cpp
uint16_t BlockMemoryLocationsArray[] = { BLOCK_LIST_LOCATIONS2 };

void SaveAwayMemory() {

    for (int i = 0; BlockMemoryLocationsArray[i] < 0xFFFF; i++) {
       MemoryBlock.BlockArray[i] = *(BASE_PTR + BlockMemoryLocationsArrary[i]);
    }
}

void RestoreFromMemory(bool skipList1) {
    int startingLocation = 0;

    if (skipList1) startingLocation += sizeof(BlockList::List1) / sizeof(uint16_t);

    for (int i = startingLocation; BlockMemoryLocationsArray[i] < 0xFFFF; i++) {
       *(BASE_PTR + BlockMemoryLocationsArrary[i]) = MemoryBlock.BlockArray[i];
    }
}
```

This presents a number of issues, since it's a pain to keep the multiple lists synchronized, and errors here tend to be fairly nasty memory corruption issues.

Some odd restrictions: we do not have a heap, we're operating on an embedded platform using armcc.

Is there a relatively clean alternative implementation that gives me

- Access to each saved away value individually
- Easy mass save/restore
- Ability to specify the location only once

**High Level Code Use**

```
SaveAwayMemory();
// Literally thousands of lines of processing... including things like the following
Write1550(MemoryBlock.BlockList.List1.Mem1450 | 0x0020);

if (Read1000() != MemoryBlock.BlockList.Mem1000) // freak out if this changed

RestoreFromMemory(true);
```

Comment: You seem to use the structs for their sizes only. Do you really need them?

Comment: @n.m. There is some intervening code between the Save/Restore where we use the structs. We pull values out of them, modify, and write to the original locations.

Comment: You can use array indices just as well for that.

Comment: Just to clarify (a few years later), array indices are useless in this case, since we don't actually have a clean mapping that 0x1000 is slot 3. And the memory address/name is the only thing we want to index on for individual reads/writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was able to draw on the back of the napkin.

```
template <int ... Values>
struct Bimap;

template <>
struct Bimap<>
{
    static const int Size = 0; 
};

template <int Value0, int ... Values>
struct Bimap<Value0, Values...>
{
    static const int Val = Value0;
    using Next = Bimap<Values...>;
    static const int Size = 1 + Next::Size;
};

template<typename A, int I>
struct Get;

template<typename A>
struct Get<A, 0>
{
    static const int Val = A::Val;
};

template<typename A, int I>
struct Get
{
    static const int Val = Get<typename A::Next, I-1>::Val;
};

template<typename A, int Val>
struct Find;

template<int Value0, int... Values>
struct Find<Bimap<Value0, Values...>, Value0>
{
    static const int Idx = 0;
};

template<int ValueToFind, int Value0, int... Values>
struct Find<Bimap<Value0, Values...>, ValueToFind>
{
    static const int Idx = 1 + Find<Bimap<Values...>, ValueToFind>::Idx;
};
```

Now what does this have to do with anything? If you have

```
using MyLocations = Bimap<0x1000, 0x1100, 0x1400, 0x1500>;
```

then

```
Get<MyLocations, 3>::Val == 0x1500
```

and

```
Find<MyLocations, 0x1500>::Idx = 3
```

Now you can declare

```
uint16_t MyBlocks[MyLocations::Size];
```

and use

```
MyBlocks[Find<MyLocations, 0x1500>::Idx] = 
  MyBlocks[Find<MyLocations, 0x1400>::Idx] | 0x777;
```

which is about equivalent to the former

```
MemoryBlock.BlockList.Mem1500 = MemoryBlock.BlockList.Mem1400 | 0x777;
```

I hope you can adapt this to your exact needs.

I'm almost sure Boost have something like that already, but I can't be bothered to find it.